# How can I immediately disable all emails using postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, mail

Is there a quick setting to disable all outgoing emails using postfix on my Ubuntu server?

I've seen [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/271443/200183) which suggests

> setting `default_transport = error: This server sends mail only locally`.

...but where would I put that setting? What is the quickest way to disable all outgoing mail from my Ubuntu server? My server has a bug and is sending out the same email over and over...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf
```

You should find there the specified line and modify it accordingly.

After that, try to restart the postfix service for the new configuration to take effect by issuing the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

Or just reboot the system.